# Show custom exit status in systemctl

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I would like to show a custom message when someone runs `systemctl status` and the script has failed.

Systemd seems to have a few built in.

If I have a script that runs `exit 200` systemctl status will out put `(code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)`

How can set the status with a custom message? I would like to be able to do `exit 199` and have it show something like `status=199/MY_CODE`

Comment: If the answer appears correct, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find no mentions in the `systemd` docs that custom exit codes are possible.  If you are interested in creating your own, you could modify systemd, re-compile and re-install, but I wouldn't recommend that. You could see `src/basic/exit-status.h` in the systemd source try as a starting point.

Comment: So based on reading the source code, what the OP is asking is not possible. The exit code to string map is a hard-coded switch statement. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/basic/exit-status.c